# How to create an adb shell am like argument parser in python?

Tags: python, parsing, command-line-arguments, argparse

The `adb shell am` [command (activity manager)](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#am) has parameters like this:

```
 [--eia <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_INT_VALUE>[,<EXTRA_INT_VALUE...]]
```

To my knowledge `argparse` is the python way to parse arguments. I'd need an action that should:

- consists of 2 *or more* arguments (eg. `--eia key1 1 2 3`) (see last point)
- is *optional*
- ***edit*** it can occour multiple times, eg. `--eia key1 1,2 --eia key2 2,1` is valid
- the type of the first argument may differ from the type of the rest
- other optional arguments like this can exist
- the example has the delimiter of a `,` but I'd like to allow delimiting with spaces, because my actual argument values may be strings and I'd like to leave parsing them to the shell (if a string should start with `-`, quotation marks help: `"-asdf"`)

An other question [has an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8411421/611007) that can do this with positional arguments:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(usage='%(prog)s [-h] file file [file ...]')
parser.add_argument('file1', nargs=1, metavar='file')
parser.add_argument('file2', nargs='+', metavar='file', help=argparse.SUPPRESS)
namespace = parser.parse_args()
namespace.file = namespace.file1 + namespace.file2
```

But I cannot see if these works for optional arguments too?

With my requirements is it a good idea to start with `argparse` at all? Are there other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- consists of 2 or more arguments (eg. --eia key1 1 2 3) (see last point)
```

There is a proposed patch that would allow `nargs` like `2 or more`, modeled on the `re {n,m}` notation.  But for now I think `nargs='+'` is your best bet.  The important thing is that it grabs the necessary arguments.  You can check for '2 or more' after `parse_args` (a custom `type` could also check that).

```
- is optional
```

Use of the `--eia` flag takes care of that

```
- edit it can occour multiple times, eg. --eia key1 1,2 --eia key2 2,1 is valid
```

With the `--eia` flag that is allowed, but only the last entry is preserved.  But `action='append'` will save each entry set as a list (or tuple?); so the namespace will have `args.eia = [['key1','1','2'],['key2',...],...]`.  Play with with action type and verify this.

```
- the type of the first argument may differ from the type of the rest
```

Leaving the values as strings, and doing your own transformation after is simplest.  You could write a custom `type` (or `action`) to check the values.  But the code would be similar to what you'd used after `argparse`.

```
- other optional arguments like this can exist
```

That's going to depend on how you write the added code.

```
- the example has the delimiter of a , but I'd like to allow delimiting with spaces, because my actual argument values may be strings and I'd like to leave parsing them to the shell (if a string should start with -, quotation marks help: "-asdf")
```

The primary shell, the one the calls your script, is the one that splits the command line into strings, primarily on spaces.  `argparse` uses `sys.argv`, that list of strings.  If that list is not what you want, you'll have to fiddle with it before passing it to `argparse.parse_args(argv)`.

A common way to test `argparse` is:

```
parser.parse_args('--eia key1 1,2 --eia key2 2,1'.split())
```

The replicates the main splitting on spaces, but does not deal with quoting and escape characters as the shell would.  There is a way of replicating the shell action, but I'd have to dig around to find it.