# Simple sort program from the command line

Tags: python

I am trying to prevent this simple sort program to accept only 1 argument when printing in reverse. this is what I type and it still goes thru:

```
python sort.py  alpha -r
```

here is my whole program:

example: python sort.py able spencer delta
to reverse:
python sort.py -r able spencer delta
python sort.py --reverse able spencer delta

```
import argparse
import sys

def wordsorter():
    argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    argparser.add_argument('user_string', nargs='*')
    argparser.add_argument("-r","-- 
reverse",action="store_true",default="False",dest="z_to_a")
args = argparser.parse_args()
if (len(sys.argv)==1 or len(sys.argv)==2):
    print("Invalid command line arguments to program. Please, supply two or more strings to sort.")
    sys.exit(1)

if args.z_to_a == True and len(sys.argv)>1:
    words_to_sort= sorted(args.user_string, reverse = True)
    print(*words_to_sort)
    print("if 1")
else:

    words_to_sort = sorted(args.user_string)
    print(*words_to_sort)
    print("if 2")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    wordsorter ()
```

When I enter one Argument without sorting in reverse it works
If I try to use reverse with one argument it should not work.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason there are 2 spaces? `sort.py  alpha`

Comment: 2 spaces or 10 spaces it doesn't matter much to argument parsing

Comment: `if (len(sys.argv)==1 or len(sys.argv)==2)` don't do this leave this to argparse

Comment: try using `if len(args.user_string) < 2:` instead of checking `sys.argv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the fact that you tell argparse to expect any number of arguments for `user_string` instead of at least two, and then check that `len(sys.argv) >= 2` (by the way, this is a better way to write that if condition), but it can be equal to 2 if you pass `-r` and only one argument for `user_string`.

You can check that `len(args.user_string) >= 2` and that should work.

If you want to do it through argparse: Unfortunately, while it is possible to tell it to expect at least **one** argument, it is not possible to directly tell it to expect at least **two**. A possible workaround is described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411218/can-argparse-in-python-2-7-be-told-to-require-a-minimum-of-two-arguments) answer.