# Python argparse optional argument consuming at least two command-line arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I am writing a program which processes *all* files in a predefined folder. Optionally, it shall process only certain *specified files* in a *specified folder*. For this I want to use an optional command line parameter `-s` or `--specify-files`.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-s", "--specify-files", type=str, metavar="FOLDER FILES", nargs="+", 
        help="Will process specified FILES in specified FOLDER. Specify at least one file. Folder path and each file name must be separated by space")
args = parser.parse_args("-s ~/custom/folder file1.txt file2.txt file34.txt".split())
print(args)
```

Output:

```
Namespace(select_files=['~/custom/folder', 'file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file34.txt'])
```

From here the program knows that `args.select_files[0]` is the folder path and `args.select_files[1:]` is a list of files to process.

Thanks to `nargs="+"` the ArgumentParser warns if the user does not specify anything, but I wonder how I could error out and warn the user if he enters less than two arguments:

```
args = parser.parse_args("-s ~/custom/folder".split())
```

Current Output:

```
Namespace(specify_files=['~/custom/folder'])
```

Expected:

```
usage: minimal.py [-h] [-s [FOLDER FILES ...]]
minimal.py: error: argument -s/--specify-files: expected at least two arguments
```

For my program, anythin less than two arguments for `-s` does not make sense. I could easily write a check for this and raise an error after `parser` has parsed the arguments, but I'd prefer if the error would already be raised before `parser.parse_args` outputs the Namespace object. Something like a `nargs="2+"` would be convenient here, if you know what I mean.

Comment: It isn't directly possible the way you're describing it. However, there is a workaround in the following link which addresses your concern.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411218/can-argparse-in-python-2-7-be-told-to-require-a-minimum-of-two-arguments

Comment: The suggested link works for positionals, but not for one optional (flagged).  But since the first string is distinct, a path, you might still want to put it in a separate argument.  Otherwise doing your own checking after parsing is perfectly fine.  `parser.error(...)` lets you use the same `argparse` format.  The Python gods will not punish you for doing this!

Comment: Thank you @hpaulj. I'll look into the parser.error() thing and implement my own check for this case. I hesitate to have the folder path parsed as an independent argument, because there is no way to enforce that two optional arguments must co-occur (optional argument for folder path would have to co-occur with the optional argument for the files). One can only enforce that two arguments exclude each other.