# How to combine multiple values for an argument using argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I'm using `argparse` to make a command line tool for my work.
I have a requirement wherein an argument should be able to take multiple values.

The argument can take only legal values.

The legal values can be any combination of values coming from a list, "ALL".

**sample.py**:

```
import argparse

sample_list = ["a", "b", "c"]

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-M', '--Module', choices=sample_list, default=default_module, help='specify the Module name')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Using the above approach the allowed values the allowed values are:

```
python sample.py -M a
```

I want that user is able to enter:

```
python sample.py -M a,b
<ok>

python sample.py -M ALL
<ok>

python sample.py -M D
<error>
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Try refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8526675/python-argparse-optional-append-argument-with-choices

Comment: You could implement a custom `type` function for that argument, which would check against `sample_list` per your rules, but there's no built-in way to do it AFAIK

Comment: Thanks @DesmondLua i got solution for my problem.

Comment: Post your solution to close out this question.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to include `ALL` is the list of allowable choices, and use either `action='append'` or `nargs='*'` to accept multiple values.  I'd leave the interpretation of `ALL` to post-parsing code.

As has been discussed in other SO questions, trying to handle comma delimited sublists is a pain.