# Python argparse: type inconsistencies when combining 'choices', 'nargs' and 'default'

Tags: python, argparse

I have the following python program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('arg', choices=['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], default='foo', nargs='*')

args = parser.parse_args()

print(args)
```

If I invoke the program like this:

```
./prog.py
```

the output is

```
Namespace(arg='foo')
```

But if I invoke the program with `foo` as an argument:

```
./prog.py foo
```

the output is

```
Namespace(arg=['foo'])
```

**Question**

How can I get `arg`'s default value to become a `list`?

**I've tried**

I've tried setting `default=['foo']` but that results in:

```
prog.py: error: argument arg: invalid choice: ['foo'] (choose from 'foo', 'bar', 'baz')
```

Comment: That 'duplicate' is about an `append` action; this is a default `store` one.  I may reopen this.

Comment: The duplicate that I rejected is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8526675/python-argparse-optional-append-argument-with-choices

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a duplicate of an old, but open, bug/issue

http://bugs.python.org/issue9625 (`argparse: Problem with defaults for variable nargs when using choices`)

A `positional` with `*` gets some special handling.  Its default is always passed through the `choices` test if you don't provide values.

Compare that with the case of an `optional`

```
In [138]: p=argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [139]: a=p.add_argument('--arg',choices=['foo','bar','baz'],nargs='*')

In [140]: p.parse_args([])
Out[140]: Namespace(arg=None)
In [141]: a.default=['foo']
In [142]: p.parse_args([])
Out[142]: Namespace(arg=['foo'])
```

The default is accepted without testing:

```
In [143]: a.default=['xxx']
In [144]: p.parse_args([])
Out[144]: Namespace(arg=['xxx'])
```

The relevant code is:

```
def _get_values(self, action, arg_strings):
    ...
    # when nargs='*' on a positional, if there were no command-line
    # args, use the default if it is anything other than None
    elif (not arg_strings and action.nargs == ZERO_OR_MORE and
          not action.option_strings):
        if action.default is not None:
            value = action.default
        else:
            value = arg_strings
        self._check_value(action, value)
```

The proposed bug/issue patch makes a small change to this block of code.

Comment: Wow, thanks for giving this so much thought even after you closed it as a duplicate. I would have closed it and forgotten about it. +1 for high quality moderation/answer! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a small work-around for that limitation in the [`typed_argparse`](https://github.com/bluenote10/typed_argparse) library. In your example, the solution would look like this:

```py
import argparse
from typed_argparse import Choices

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    "arg", 
    choices=Choices("foo", "bar", "baz"),  # Wrap the choices in Choices
    default=["foo"],  # Use any list like default
    nargs="*",
)
```

The implementation of [`Choices`](https://github.com/bluenote10/typed_argparse/blob/5d18420bd522dc615d63d651cc1fa43815bb9afe/typed_argparse/choices.py) is quite simple, if you prefer something copy/pasteable.