# argparse: How to allow empty list with nargs="*" and choices

Tags: python, argparse

In `argparse`, how can I create an optional positional command line option that takes multiple arguments which all need to be part of a list of choices?

In the following example, I want to allow any subset of the list `['a', 'b', 'c']` – i.e. `['a']`, `['a', 'c']`, ... and, crucially, the empty list `[]`. I was expecting the following to achieve that, but it fails if the argument is omitted.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('letters', nargs='*', choices=['a', 'b', 'c'])
args = parser.parse_args()
```

---

```
error: argument letters: invalid choice: [] (choose from 'a', 'b', 'c')
```

---

**UPDATE**: I have since found that `choices=['a', 'b', 'c', []]` appears to do the job. That strikes me as inconsistent as it suggests that `argparse` checks for `[] in choices` which would then imply that `['a']` should be in `choices` as well (rather than `'a'`).

Comment: Any object that support the `in` operator can be passed to choices.  It is odd though that you need to use an empty list rather than an empty string or `None` to accomplish an empty choice.

Comment: Agreed. `None` and `''` were the first things I tried when I got the error. Although I was expecting the check to be along the lines of `all([_ in choices for _ in args])`, which shouldn't require the explicit inclusion in choices.

Comment: The `*` positional is satisfied with a `[]` empty list of inputs.  But it shouldn't be passing it through the choices test.  I'll have to look at the code to see what's happening.  It would be in the `_get_values` and `_get_value` methods.  I'm surprised I don't recall seeing a bug/issue about this.

Comment: A related issue just got more attention: https://bugs.python.org/issue9625,  Other links  https://bugs.python.org/issue27227, https://bugs.python.org/issue16878, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41750896/python-argparse-type-inconsistencies-when-combining-choices-nargs-and-def

Comment: Are repeats supposed to be allowed? I mean like `parser.parse_args(['a', 'a'])` doesn't raise an error.

Comment: @jhansen Please, just read again what you wrote: "optional positional command line option". So, is this supposed to be a POSITIONAL or OPTIONAL argument? In `argparse` there's a substantial difference

Answer (score 1):

I think this question (asking for an empty list default) is basically a special case of the [more general question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41750896/1804173), asking for other defaults.

To adapt [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69859603/1804173) based on [`typed_argparse`](https://github.com/bluenote10/typed_argparse) to this specific case:

```py
import argparse
from typed_argparse import Choices

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    "letters", 
    choices=Choices("a", "b", "c"),  # Wrap the choices in Choices
    default=[],  # Empty list possible as default
    nargs="*",
)
```

The implementation of [`Choices`](https://github.com/bluenote10/typed_argparse/blob/5d18420bd522dc615d63d651cc1fa43815bb9afe/typed_argparse/choices.py) is quite simple, if you prefer something copy/pasteable.