# Get name of argument instead of dest in argparse.Action's __call__()

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I'm using some of the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4195302/691859), particularly the part which raises an `argparse.ArgumentTypeError`:

```
raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(
                "argument '{f}' requires between {nmin} and {nmax} "
                "arguments".format(f=self.dest, nmin=nmin, nmax=nmax))
```

However, I've also tacked on the `append` action behavior into my subclass' `__call__()`, which means that one or more of these repeated arguments may be formatted incorrectly and could raise that `ArgumentTypeError`.

So when I use this for such an argument in a parser:

```
parse = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-a", "--append-arg", action=append_range(2,3), default=[])
```

And I get an error from typing the wrong number of arguments, I get something like this:

```
argparse.ArgumentTypeError: argument 'append_arg' requires between 2 and 3 arguments
```

Great, that's how I'd like it to be used. But now the list of arguments is named `append_arg` in the namespace. I'd like it to be named `list_of_repeated_args` or whatever. So if I do:

```
parser.add_argument("-a", "--append-arg", action=append_range(2,3), default=[], dest="list_of_repeated_args")
```

Then I get this for the error instead:

```
argparse.ArgumentTypeError: argument 'list_of_repeated_args' requires between 2 and 3 arguments
```

That's not what I wanted. Sure, I could change the function to take the name I want as an argument, but I'd like to just use the name automatically. Is there a way to do this? (i.e., what should I place instead of `f=self.dest`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the solution. The `__call__()` method of the custom `argparse.Action` has the `option_string` argument which, according to [the docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#action), is:

> The option string that was used to invoke this action. The `option_string` argument is optional, and will be absent if the action is associated with a positional argument.

Sure enough, if I change the following code **to use `option_string` instead**:

```
raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(
                "argument '{f}' requires between {nmin} and {nmax} "
                "arguments".format(f=option_string, nmin=nmin, nmax=nmax))
```

I get (assuming I'm using the abbreviated form) the desired effect:

```
argparse.ArgumentTypeError: argument '-a' requires between 2 and 3 arguments
```